# How to avoid edit mode when I advance with TAB key after edit a cell in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

This is my question. When I edit a cell in a QTableView, I would like that if I press TAB key, the current cell is updated, but the next cell isn't in edit mode.

I have try to create a eventFilter in a table, but it doesn't work. Neither if I create the eventFilter in the editor widget of the delegate.
This is my try of a eventFilter in the QTableView. My idea is that if the current cell is in the last column and row and the current row is not empty, I insert another row (this works fine) and if I am editing any cell, when I press TAB I can place on the next cell but without Edit Mode

This is a snippet of the code:

```
bool MiTabla::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QModelIndex indice = this->currentIndex();
        QKeyEvent *ke =static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
        switch (ke->key())
        {
        case (Qt::Key_Delete):
        {
            if (this->selectionModel()->isRowSelected(indice.row(),QModelIndex()))
            {
                //borrarLineas();
            }
            else
            {
                this->model()->setData(this->currentIndex(),"",Qt::EditRole);
            }
            break;
        }
        case (Qt::Key_Tab):
        {
            if (indice.row() == this->model()->rowCount(QModelIndex())-1
                    && indice.column() == this->model()->columnCount(QModelIndex())-1
                    && !NombreVacio())
            {
                this->model()->insertRow(this->model()->rowCount(QModelIndex()));
                QModelIndex ind = this->model()->index(indice.row()+1,0);
                this->setCurrentIndex(ind);
            }
            else //this doesn't work
            {
                QModelIndex ind = this->model()->index(indice.row(),indice.column()+1);
                this->setCurrentIndex(ind);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Sketch of solution: subclass QStyledItemDelegate, override its `eventFilter`, do a slightly different handling for the Tab key, otherwise call the base class implementation. Cf. the builtin handling: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemdelegate.cpp.html#476

Comment: What return value of eventFilter method? Did you tried to return "true" for `Key_Tab` case?

Comment: Thank you peppe. It just I was looking for. And ramzes2, the other clue was return false for let the table "use" the TabKey pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. I have solved it as you said.
I have reimplement the *eventFilter()* function in the delegate class (subclassed from QStyledItemDelegate) as below:

```
bool DelegadoNombre::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent* key = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (key->key()==Qt::Key_Tab || key->key()==Qt::Key_Enter || key->key()==Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            QLineEdit *editor=qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj);
            emit commitData(editor);
            emit closeEditor(editor, QStyledItemDelegate::NoHint);
        }
        else
        {
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function says to editor of the delegate that if Tab Key is pressed it must commit the data and close the editor but no open the next editor in Edit Mode *QStyledItemDelegate::NoHint*.
Also, return false for allow to the table use this event